# i want to run my python program(not script) with start command which is a method in that python program file to be executed

Tags: python, cmd

Hi have python program in which a start method is defined, in start method i am calling a win32serviceutil.StartService(service) method to start a service, like

```
import os, platform, subprocess

try:
    import win32serviceutil
except:
    os.system("pip install pywin32")
    os.system("pip install pypiwin32")
    import win32serviceutil

OS = platform.system() #will get you the platform/OS
print("You are using ", OS)

if __name__=='__main__':

    service = 'WSearch'
    def startByCLI():
        cmd = 'net start '+service
        os.system(cmd)

    def startByPython():
        # subprocess.check_output(["sc", "start", service], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        win32serviceutil.StartService(service)

    if OS=='Windows':
        try:
            output = startByPython()
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.output)
            print(e.returncode)
            #os.system('python test2.py')
            subprocess.call("python ./install.py asadmin", shell=True)
            startByCLI()
```

so what i actually want is i want to run the start method from command promt like this

```
python ./myfile.py startByPython
```

and it will trigger the `startByPython` method in `myfile.py`

many thanks in advance

Comment: What _exactly_ is your question? What did you try and what did not work? Does your script actually call `start`?

Comment: you must use pyinstaller or py2exe to make it into an executable... or you need to right click any python file and select "open with" and check the always open with box, and select python as the program to open with ... all "start XXXX" does is tell the operating system to run that thing with its default program handler

Comment: @JoranBeasley would [command-line-arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#command-line-arguments) and when given 'start' spawning the process as detached Process be enough to do it?

Comment: @DYZ thanks for reply, and i have python program in which a start method is defined, in start method i am calling a win32serviceutil.StartService(service) method to start a service, like  so what i actually want please see a question again i have edited it ith code too

Comment: hey please view the answer now , i hope you will get me what i wanted actually

Answer (score 1):

Hey all thanks for your attention,
i wanted to run my file.py file with argument from command line like:

$ /usr/bin/python myfile.py start

i got the solution which is

> ```
>   def main():
>    # read arguments from the command line and 
>    # check whether at least two elements were entered
>    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
>       print "Usage: python aws.py {start|stop}\n"
>       sys.exit(0)
>    else:
>       action = sys.argv[1]
> ```

```
   if action == "start":
      startInstance()
   elif action == "stop":
      stopInstance()
   else:
      print "Usage: python aws.py {start|stop}\n"
```